# Objective-C extensions generates "may not respond warning" in some cases

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios

The code builds with a single warning and generates the expected output "Hello, World!"

Example file "TestClass.h"

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface TestClass : NSObject {
}

- (void)foobar;
@end
```

Example file "TestClass.m"

```
#import "TestClass.h"

@implementation TestClass
- (void)say {
    // Compiler output "warning: 'TestClass' may not respond to '-hello'"
    [self hello]; 
}

- (void)hello {
    NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
}

- (void)foobar {
    [self say];
}
@end

@interface TestClass ()
- (void)say;
- (void)hello;
@end
```

The compiler warning can be avoided by putting the "hello" method above "say" in the @implementation section. But it's annoying to be depended on the order you put your methods. Is there any way around this compiler warning, without having to put your methods in any specific order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't. **Period**.

The compiler parses your code top-down, so please, just put your private `@interface` defintion **above** your `@implementation` and you'll be all good to go.

Comment: Right, how stupid of me. I tried changing the order of the methods inside the implementation. But I failed to try moving the extension definition "@interface TestClass ()" to the top of the file. That resolves my problems indeed, thanks.

Comment: .... and this very question is why class extensions were created in the first place (this and the ability to promote a readonly property to readwrite). A class extension's methods act *just* like methods declared in the @interface, unlike a category.  But, as Jacob answered, the extension has to be visible before the @implementation is compiled!